# Flyway disable Delete migrations

Tags: sql, version-control, flyway

I have a problem with flyway migrations in different versions of my application.
For example I have two versions of my project - `1.0` and `2.0`. In version `2.0` I have a migration script `V1__add_table.sql` with content:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    bar boolean
);
```

When I run my project version `2.0` migration `V1__add_table.sql` gets applied and I can see it in my `flyway_schema_history` table with type `SQL`.
Then I go to project version `1.0` and run it. This version of project doesn't contain any migrations so in `flyway_schema_history` table I get another row added for `V1__add_table.sql` with type `DELETED`.
The problem is that when I come back to project version `2.0` Flyway tries to execute migration again, but fails because it was already applied.

How could I disable creation of `DELETE` migrations? I expect that Flyway would just silently ignore migrations, that were already applied checking it with `success` column.

Comment: This isn't really a *Git* issue: you'd get the same thing with any version control system. The solution I've seen for this (in general, with migrations, not specific to Flyway which I have no idea what it is) is to have "reverse migrations" that must be applied down downgrading.

Comment: @torek, But it worked fine with older version of Flyway. Reverse migrations are redundant in such case (and as I know they are available in paid version of FLyway) cause just having unused table `foo` in version `1.0` is not a problem.

Comment: Is the fundamental problem that you're switching project, but leaving the same database in the back end? Would it be best for you to have a different database in each case? Or reset the database?

Comment: Mind you, I think that @marcin's solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
flyway.ignorePendingMigrations=true
```

with your flyway installation. It is useful when schema history table indicates that a migration has already been performed by newer deployment `2.0` but are not yet available in this `1.0` version.

reference: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/ignoreFutureMigrations

Comment: `ignorePendingMigrations` doesn't work, 'DELETED' record are still added to `flyway_schema_version` and then are reapplied.